# Where are the logs stored when u bootstrap on a node

Tags: knife, chef-infra

What is the location or path of the logs stored after bootstraping on a node?

For example, from the workstation,

```
knife cookbook bootstrap IP -x name -P passwd -r role[dummy]
```

Where does the logs gets stored ..?

Answer (score 0):

The logs are stored in `/var/log/chef` on most systems:

```
/var/log/chef
```